# Where can I find gnome-alsamixer on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: alsa, 20.04, asus, soundcard

I'm preparing new setup for my work with ASUS PRIME H310M-F R2.0 Mainboard. The problem is front audio panel is not working. And I googled people telling try with `gnome-alsamixer`. But I can't find it on ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can install **qasmixer** and run it with c option to select soundcard , f.i.:
  `qasmixer -c 0`
- You can also select correct audio device in the view => "show device" box, then save configuration by selecting "from last session" in settings => startup
- Additionnal capture settings by clicking the mic button in the bottom right

[image: qasmixer]

Comment: If you're looking for the Mixer Device and Card selectors on the right, press `F6`. "Card" may mean virtual device depending on your arch.

Comment: 29Jun23.. I used this with my Dell G15-5520 and I can confirm it works and I could get the sound to work with the same level as on Windows 11.

Answer (score 3):

Install `alsamixergui` using:

```
sudo apt install alsamixergui
```

Comment: Or you can just type <alsamixer> in the terminal, and you'll get the terminal version.

Comment: there's also an `alsa-tools-gui` just to cause confusion.  The `alsamixergui` was preferred.